# How to prevent to input alphabet into datagridview cell in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am working on sale bill application in vb.net.
I have datagridview1 in which 6th column is for value of rate of item. In this column i want to allow only numbers and '.'. How can I do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should just let the user enter whatever they want and then handle the `CellValidating` event and check for a number at that point. Preventing some characters being entered is possible but requires a reasonable amount of work to be done properly, e.g. preventing invalid data being pasted in is not trivial, so you'd still have to validate anyway.

Comment: One alternative might be to use a `NumericUpDown` as the editing control, either manually or using a custom column type, but that isn't necessarily appropriate in all circumstances.

Comment: Is there any method which prevent input alphabets in datagridviewcell?

Comment: You can handle the `KeyPress` event of the editing control, just as you can for a regular `TextBox` (lots of examples on the web), but that won't stop someone pasting invalid data into a cell.

Answer (score 1):

Check the code below you have to cast the cell to TextBox then deal with it

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
Dim txt As TextBox = TryCast(e.Control, TextBox)
  If txt IsNot Nothing Then
    RemoveHandler txt.KeyPress, AddressOf Txt_KeyPress
    AddHandler txt.KeyPress, AddressOf Txt_KeyPress
    End If
 End Sub
Private Sub Txt_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs)
   If Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) AndAlso Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
    e.Handled = True 
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks to answer. Now if I put alphabet first time this code are not working. But after that for every edit this code works fine. Pls tell me what will be the problem.

Comment: The user can still paste invalid data into those cells.

Comment: @jmcilhinney For copy paste there I manage within cellvaluechanged  event. pls share me ifyou have any other solution. thank you.

Comment: You validate a cell on the `CellValidating` event, as the name suggests. If the `Value` has already changed then it's too late for a data source that only accepts numbers.